# How to add more tables to firebase database?

Tags: json, firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to build a crud project that connect to Firebase database.
I'm coming from a LAMP stack environment. I don't know much about this MEAN stack just yet. I normally would write a migration script for these kind of tasks.

I'm trying to add 3 more tables.

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**database.rules.json**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "contacts": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "logs": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "cards": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Here is the result on my real time firebase

[image]

What did I forget to do or didn't do ? 
Should I use the + sign directly in the firebase ? 
But I feel that would be manually.

---

How would one go about and achieve something like this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't have "tables".  You can think of it like one big JSON document with hierarchical key/value pairs.  You impose whatever organization on that document that you need to suit the requirements of your application.

Defining security rules as you did in database.rules.json doesn't actually create any data in your database.  Database rules merely define the access rules for that data that does actually exist in the database.

You add data with the client SDKs or the [admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).  You can use the console too if you want to enter data manually.  Most people would not populate their data manually unless it was very small.

I suggest going over the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) and look at some [samples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/) to get better acquainted with the way data storage works with Realtime Database.